# How to save to Firebase Database?

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to write to a Firebase database for the last few days. I'm new to C#, but I've read all of the documentation from Firebase on how to save data. I asked a question a few days ago and created this code using the advice received, but although it writes each directory, the actual data saved shows as {}.

Any advice what I could change to get this to write properly?

Thank you, but I used this code and the result is still {}. Any idea what could be wrong? I'm using Unity and am calling AddNewUserData when someone clicks a submit button. I eventually am going to replace "email" with emailText.text which stores the user's email address, but for now I'm just trying to create a working script to write data to the database, so I'm not concerned about anything other than being able to write valid data to the database in any way. Please help.

```
public class User
{               
    public int round { get; set; }
    public int lives { get; set; }
    public int level { get; set; }
    public int currentScore { get; set; }
    public int totalScore { get; set; }
    public User(int round, int lives, int level, int currentScore, int totalScore)
    {

        this.round = round;
        this.lives = lives;
        this.level = level;
        this.currentScore = currentScore;
        this.totalScore = totalScore;
    }
}
  public void AddNewUserData()
  {

    DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
    var json = JsonUtility.ToJson(new User(1, 3, 1, 0, 0));
    root.Child("users").Child("email").SetValueAsync(json);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data try SetRawJsonValueAsync

```
root.Child("users").Child("email").SetRawJsonValueAsync(json);
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work, it doesn't update the database at all with that code.

Comment: Please post your code and any screenshots showing that the data is saved as {} in the database.

Comment: Literally just got it to work about 10 minutes ago. I removed the get/set and manually set the int value of a string like this:

    public int round = int.Parse("1");

For some reason that worked, when nothing I've tried over the last few days did. The RawJsonValue was necessary too though so thank you.